# Как скопировать всё перечисленное в файле resource.qrc, в папку куда собирается программа? Qt

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, copy

Сейчас приходиться добавлять, каждый новый файл руками в `main.cpp`:

```
class MainWindow;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFileInfo jsFileInfo(QDir::currentPath() + "/qwebchannel.js");
    if (!jsFileInfo.exists())
        QFile::copy(":/qwebchannel.js",jsFileInfo.absoluteFilePath());

    QFileInfo htmlFileInfo(QDir::currentPath() + "/index.html");
    if (!htmlFileInfo.exists())
        QFile::copy(":/index.html",htmlFileInfo.absoluteFilePath());

    QFileInfo pngFileInfo(QDir::currentPath() + "/marker.png");
    if (!pngFileInfo.exists())
        QFile::copy(":/marker.png",pngFileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
...
}
```

чтоб он копировался в папку куда собирается программа.
Возможно все перечисленное в  resource.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>index.html</file>
        <file>qwebchannel.js</file>
        <file>marker.png</file>
        <file>conf/db.conf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

копировать автоматически, в папку куда собирается программа? без дополнительного кода в `main.cpp`.
Например, чтоб с помощью `foreach` перебирались все файлы перечисленные в `resource.qrc` и копировались в папку куда собирается программа.
Поделитесь пожалуйста кодом или предложениями. Думаю ответ будет полезен не только для меня. Нужна реализация по Windows и Linux.

Comment: вот наверное https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509799/how-to-get-list-of-files-stored-in-a-qrc-qt-resorce-file

Comment: QDir::currentPath() не обязательно показывает где исполняемый файл лежит, надежнее argv[0] использовать

Comment: @Pavel Gridin У меня большое приложение и вывелось не только, что в resource.qrc перечислено. Возможно вы вести только то что в resource.qrc?

Comment: а что там ещё то есть? двоеточие вроде как на корень ресурсов должно указывать...

Comment: @Pavel Gridin Куча файлов типа:":/qt-project.org/windows/cursors/images/splitvcursor_48.png"
":/qt-project.org/windows/cursors/images/splithcursor_32.png"
":/qt-project.org/windows/cursors/images/splitvcursor_32.png"
":/qt-project.org/windows/cursors/images/splithcursor_64.png"
":/qt-project.org/windows/cursors/images/splitvcursor_64.png"
":/qt-project.org/windows/openglblacklists"
":/qt-project.org/windows/openglblacklists/default.json"
":/qpdf"
":/qpdf/qpdfa_metadata.xml"
":/qpdf/sRGB2014.icc"

Comment: @Pavel Gridin    315 строк вывелось .     QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    int n=0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        qDebug() <<n<< it.next();
        n++;
    }

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88526/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-pavel-gridin).

Comment: поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь, но если rc файл добавлен в .pro, он будет автоматически "вкомпилирован" в исполняемый файл и ничего никуда  вручную копировать не надо

Comment: @Bearded Beaver  Вы не правы, у меня в pro включён RESOURCES += \
    resource.qrc.... Но он не копирует ресурсные файлы в папку куда собирается проект.

Comment: @Bearded Beaver может напишите какой код надо прописать в .pro файл чтоб эти файлы копировались в проект

Comment: в папку с проектом он ничего копировать не должен, ресурс упаковывается внутрь исполняемого файла

Comment: @Bearded Beaver  факт что у меня не работает приложение, если я ручками не перенесу ресурсные файлы HTML и JS , conf.db в папку куда собирается программа

Comment: значит вы неправильно работаете с файлами. покажите пример обращения к файлу из ресурсов

Comment: @Bearded Beaver  url(:/resource/marker.png)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88543/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-bearded-beaver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно все свои файлы  в ресурсах переложить в отдельный каталог, ибо как выяснилось Qt добавляет в ресурсы много чего своего, в данном примере пользовательские ресурсы лежат в ":/res". Сам пример:

```
    QDirIterator it(":/res", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    QString exePath = QFileInfo(argv[0]).absolutePath();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        QString srcFileName = it.next();
        QString dstFileName = exePath + "/" + QFileInfo(srcFileName).fileName();
        if(!QFile::exists(dstFileName))
            QFile::copy(srcFileName, dstFileName);
    }
```